# Mobile website Development Framework Vs Standard website developement Frameworks

Tags: mobile

We are working on a web application and done all the coding in Ruby on rails. Now we are thinking of a mobile website. (Think of m.facebook.com).

Now the question is:--

1. **Why should I use any mobile development frameworks to develop mobile website** (frameworks like [Sencha.com](http://Sencha.com)
   [The-m-project.net](http://The-m-project.net)
   [SproutCore.com](http://SproutCore.com) and many more frameworks are there )
2. Whats the benefit of using these frameworks instead of developing mobile website using ruby-on rails (Maintain the screen size and think of other optimizations like no images, no Jquery etc.)
3. For touch screen mobiles is there anything else i need to focus.

Suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing stopping you from developing a mobile site using just html/css (haml/sass if you prefer) for the front-end and rails powered backend. 
If the screen size is your only concern, you can get css templates for the mobile devices you are targeting and they should be sufficient. For a generic mobile website, all you need to take care is that all the content can be leniarized in a visually aesthetic fashion.
However,in case you need to create an interactive web site whose user interface is specially optimized for touch enabled devices (eg. what happen if a user performs a flick gesture, or what if user presses the screens for a long duration etc.) then using a javascript framework particularly designed for mobile devices can provide you significant advantage and help you take advantage of the event model which considerably differs from traditional web pages.

Answer (score 0):

hm on one side a framewprk like sencha or phonegap is easier, you can build the whole app with css, javascript and html, buts its no native app

on the otherside for native apps you will have to learn java, objective c or cocoa or antoher language and also have to have a developer account from apple

well also we use in our agency ruby on rails with jquery and so on

Comment: I am not talking about native apps. We already working on it using phonegap. I am more concerned about mobile websites.

Comment: well then there should be dojo toolkit and / or jquery mobile but well phonegap and sencha use many built in features of the devices like the compass and so on, also i dont know a ruby o rails framework thta is almost the same as sencha (touch) or phonegap, think these frameworks like phonegap are easier and better to work with. Mobile Websites should also use all the modern features like touch events and geolocation and so on and the best solution for

Comment: this would be somethink like phonegap. we use ruby on rails just for big company projects with scaffolding and cause of the crud features. also for ruby on rails you need a good hoster with ruby on rails. i would prefer phonegap or sencha for mobile sites =) .